# Data reconciliation with two different dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, loops, merge

I'm trying to compare two dataframes ,DF1 with DF2 .Both are having the same columns but different number of rows.I would like to go through each ID in column ID in DF1 and Check if the same ID exists in the Column ID of DF2.If the IDs in both data frame matches then I need to check if the value in DF1[A] of first dataframe for each ID  matches with the value in DF2[A1]  of the second dataframe.If the value of DF1[ID] matches with DF2[ID] then check for A and A1. For each ID , If A in DF1 and A1 in DF2 are matching then print 'TRUE' or else print 'False'.I need a pythonic (preferably loops rather than merging dataframes and looking whether the records are matching using .isin method) way of doing the reconciliation.

```
DF1                                DF2

ID  A                              ID      A1
10X  Fever                         11Y     Vomiting
11Y  Vomiting                      10X     Fever
12Z  Headache                      12Z     Headache
13A  Pain                          13A     Pain
14B  Dizziness                     14B     Irritation
15C  irritation
```

The following method gives me somewhat satisfactory results. But I'm wondering if there are any other ways to do it. ex: Loops

```
Result = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on=['ID'], how='inner')
Result['True/False']=DF2.A1.isin(DF1.A).astype(np.str)
```

suggestions are most welcome